# TSQL - Transaction rolls back - PAGEIOLATCH_EX wait type - SQL SErver 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql

64 bit windows server 2008, sql server 2005. 4 processors. Database is in simple recovery model- when the following batch script is run, the transaction starts to rollback at "`ALTER TABLE PS_RC_CASE_AUDIT ADD Z_TMP_ALTER_1 NVARCHAR(80) NULL`" - the following are the wait types observed. We have had to roll back this transaction already a couple of time because the log file was filling up and we ran out of disk space. We added more space today, and the transaction still rolls back.  Any ideas?

```
PAGEIOLATCH_EX    5006.53 
SLEEP_BPOOL_FLUSH 931.00
LCK_M_SCH_S   466.77
IO_COMPLETION     226.16
```

Below is the script:

```
USE [DBNAME]
go
SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS ON
go
--  
-- Alters for record PS_RC_CASE_AUDIT 
--        RC_DESCRLONG - move to table end (LONGCHAR) 
--        RSLN_SUMMARY - change 
--     CASE_VISIBILITY - add 
--             BO_NAME - add 
--           REASON_CD - add 

-- Start the Transaction 


-- Data Conversion 


-- Add Columns 

ALTER TABLE PS_RC_CASE_AUDIT ADD CASE_VISIBILITY NVARCHAR(4) NULL
go
ALTER TABLE PS_RC_CASE_AUDIT ADD BO_NAME NVARCHAR(50) NULL
go
ALTER TABLE PS_RC_CASE_AUDIT ADD REASON_CD NVARCHAR(10) NULL
go
ALTER TABLE PS_RC_CASE_AUDIT ADD Z_TMP_ALTER_1 NVARCHAR(80) NULL
go
ALTER TABLE PS_RC_CASE_AUDIT ADD X_TMP_ALTER_1 NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL
go
UPDATE PS_RC_CASE_AUDIT SET  
    X_TMP_ALTER_1 = RC_DESCRLONG, 
    Z_TMP_ALTER_1 = RSLN_SUMMARY
go

-- Set Default Values 

UPDATE PS_RC_CASE_AUDIT SET CASE_VISIBILITY = ' ', BO_NAME = ' ',
 REASON_CD = ' '
go

-- Modify NULLability 

ALTER TABLE PS_RC_CASE_AUDIT ALTER COLUMN Z_TMP_ALTER_1 NVARCHAR(80)
 NOT NULL
go
ALTER TABLE PS_RC_CASE_AUDIT ALTER COLUMN CASE_VISIBILITY NVARCHAR(4)
 NOT NULL
go
ALTER TABLE PS_RC_CASE_AUDIT ALTER COLUMN BO_NAME NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
go
ALTER TABLE PS_RC_CASE_AUDIT ALTER COLUMN REASON_CD NVARCHAR(10) NOT
 NULL
go

-- Drop Old Columns 

ALTER TABLE PS_RC_CASE_AUDIT DROP COLUMN RC_DESCRLONG
go
ALTER TABLE PS_RC_CASE_AUDIT DROP COLUMN RSLN_SUMMARY
go

-- Rename Changed Columns 

sp_rename 'PS_RC_CASE_AUDIT.X_TMP_ALTER_1', RC_DESCRLONG, 'COLUMN'
go
sp_rename 'PS_RC_CASE_AUDIT.Z_TMP_ALTER_1', RSLN_SUMMARY, 'COLUMN'
go
COMMIT
go

-- Done 
go
COMMIT
go
```

Comment: Please use the code tags so we can read this...

Comment: Thanks!  Now can  you give us the schema?  Are you sure  this column doesn't already exist?

Comment: Have you tried running each line one at a time to what the specific error is?

Answer (score 1):

Are you still running out of disk space with the T-Log filling up? 
Can you not run the Add, update, modify, drop and then rename stages of your script on their own to avoid the log filling up.